# SSRS Free3of9 Barcode font no embedding

Tags: sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I really hope someone can help me with this issue.  I have an SSRS report that uses Free3of9 Extended barcodes.  My issue is that SSRS does not embed the font file when exporting to PDF.

Here is what is going on:

I have two servers that I am trying to test this on, Server 2003 and Server 2008.  Both are using Sql Reporting Services 2008 R2.  They both have the font files installed in the Windows Font directory.

On Server 2003, when I run the report I am able to see the barcode correctly and it exports to a PDF correctly.  The issue here is that when my application calls the same report, I can see the barcode but it does not export to PDF.  The computer that is running the application also has the font files installed.

On Server 2008, when I run the report I am able to see the barcode but the font file is not embedded in the PDF on export.  Calling the report from my external application like I do above has the same affect.

I installed the fonts to both servers the same way and they are both using the same report created in Report Building 2008 R2.  Since installing the fonts both servers have been fully patched and restarted.

Any ideas how this can be resolved?  I am providing a link below with the Font files in question and a sample report that shows correctly in SSRS but not when you export it.

Thanks.

[Font files and Sample SSRS report](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60808326/free3of9.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Same results after installing the font on the local dev machine and SSRS report server. It renders PDFs locally but not on the remote machine.

SSRS to PDF conversion list 14 standard PDF fonts as: Times−Roman, Times−Bold, Times−Italic, Times−BoldItalic, Helvetica, Helvetica−Bold, Helvetica−Oblique, Helvetica−BoldOblique, Courier, Courier−Bold, Courier−Oblique, Courier−BoldOblique, Symbol, ZapfDingbats

You may need to find another solution than a font.

You could make a webpage to render jpg files as a url reference in the report. Generated the barcode jpg files using an iTextSharp reference, specifically iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CODE128

Pass a url paramiter of the text to generate a bar code of.